Kafka with websocket
Issue Description:

Single Consumer: When Kafka is used by a single consumer, it works as expected, and the log shows the following partition assignment:
test-consumer-group: partitions assigned: [kafka-topic-0]


Multiple Consumers: When multiple consumers are using Kafka under the same consumer group, the log shows:
test-consumer-group: partitions assigned: []

This indicates that no partitions are assigned, and the system does not work correctly.


Requirement:
I want the log to display the partition assignment for all consumers, similar to the following:
test-consumer-group: partitions assigned: [kafka-topic-0]


Partition assignment already gets logged... Plus, there is no native websockets compared to Apache Pulsar, so what are you using?
